# Record available hard drive space to a variable in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Ok, so I have done some research and I have got this far:

```
wmic logicaldisk get freespace
```

Output:

```
FreeSpace
5136646144
171245400064
```

This is doing all of my hard drives when I only want it to do C:\  and remove the FreeSpace words. Finally, I want it to then be recorded in a variable in batch file

Comment: Update, found how to do it just for C:                                                     wmic logicaldisk where "DeviceID='C:'" get FreeSpace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (`"wmic logicaldisk  where name='C:' get  FreeSpace /format:value"`) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%#") do set "%%a"
)

echo %freespace%
```

the additional inner `FOR` is for cleaning [redundant CR characters](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266)